# Dynamic Image Creation With Gruff and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruff

So I am new to Ruby on Rails and I was wondering if there was a way to create a gruff image without saving it to the disk and have it embedded inside a view static page with other html code. Right now I am using:
send_data(graph.to_blob, :filename => "stock.png", :type => 'image/png', :disposition=> 'inline')

But what that does is it overwrites the html code (header, tables) in my static page instead of showing both concurrently.